# Gradle Sync Failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[image: Tengo este error he leido e intentado de todo pero el error sigue.]

Tengo este error he leido e intentado de todo pero el error sigue.
Gradle project sync failed.

Comment: Esto se debe a infinidad de causas!, revisa que mensajes de error obtienes en la consola.

Comment: Has intentado de todo, pero creo que es importante comentar a que te refieres con todo.

Comment: Verificaste las versiones de los sdk, que tienes instalados es decir si estas trabajando con api 27,o 26 etc... asi como la version del sdk build tool sea la correcta y que este instalada

Comment: Tal vez tienes muchas librerias, has intentado usar
        multiDexEnabled true   , en gradle ?  aunque no tenga mucho que ver almenos que tengas muchas librerias , esto me ha permitido ver el error más claramente